# How to call a function from one project in another one?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a solution consisting of two projects:

**Project1**
containing a single file *program.cpp*

```
namespace Program1 {
  void foo() { ... }
}
```

**Project2**
containing another single file *program.cpp* in which I'd like to call *foo()*

```
namespace Program2 {
  void bar() { Program1::foo() }
}
```

I have set:

- project dependencies (Program2 depends on Program1)
- references in Program2 to Program1

But still I recieve an error

```
error C2653: 'Program1' : is not a class or namespace name
```

What else do I need to do to call *Program1::foo()* in *Project2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the header file which contains the declaration:

#### Project1 - Program.h

```
namespace Program1 {
  void foo();
}
```

#### Project2 - Program.cpp

```
#include "Program.h"
namespace Program2 {
  void bar() { Program1::foo() }
}
```

Comment: I just needed to specify the path, now it works fine, thanks.

Comment: Hi @Jan, how to set the path ?

Comment: @shivaR in the build command in that case: `g++ path/to/program1.cpp path/to/program2.cpp -o debug.exe`, use `-L` option for path to libraries (if any)